# Getting the control present inside ItemTemplate of a TabControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am developing a class derived from "Control" class to create a custom control. In the **Generic.xaml** file I have added the below code to create a Tab control template:

```
    <Style  TargetType="{x:Type local:NavigationPane}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type local:NavigationPane}">   
                <TabControl Name="tabControl"   Margin="1" TabStripPlacement="Left">   
                    <TabControl.ItemTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate >
                              <Button Name="buttonImage" >
                                    <Image Name="img" Height="24" Width="24" Source ="{Binding PageIcon}"/>
                                </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                </TabControl>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In the NavigationPane class I want to access control named "btnImage" and I want to add an event handler to it.

I tried the below approach:

```
  ContentPresenter cp = tabControl.Template.FindName("PART_SelectedContentHost",     tabControl) as ContentPresenter;
       btnImage = tabControl.ContentTemplate.FindName("btnImage", cp) as Button;
                if (btnImage != null)
                {
                    btnImage.Click += btnImage_Click;
                }
```

Looks like the above code can only get the items in the ContentTemplate not from ItemTemplate. I would like to know what is the approach to get the pointer to the control which is in Item Template, that is the header part of Tab Control.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong,  but it doesn't look like you're using the `TabControl.Header` anywhere in your code... are you sure you're using the correct terminology? Are you just looking for the [How to: Find DataTemplate-Generated Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN?

Comment: You may try overriding the OnApplyTemplate() in your control and then use Button b = GetTemplateChild("MyButton") as Button; in that override

Comment: Sorry for the terminology. I meant to say that the control which is present inside of a ItemTemplate of a tab control. In this example it is to get the "btnImage".

Comment: Krishna, I already tried this approach. It is returning null as button is not the direct child.

Comment: I see that you are trying to access the button click. Can you implement an ICommand and bind that to a RelayCommand in your class?

Comment: Sheridan, I tried the approach explained in "How to: Find DataTemplate-Generated Elements" link which you provided. Looks like it can only fetch the elements present in the **ContentTemplate**, but not from ItemTemplate. It is also returning null.